# Giving enemies Health/Multiple hits

Tags: sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game with multiple types of zombies that take multiple hits to kill. For example, I have a runner zombie sprite node that has 2 health. When it is hit once it speeds up and when it is hit again it dies. I have been trying to get my enemies to be multiple hits and I never figured it out. Do I make a class with various properties such as a health variable or do I make a function? Identify all of the enemies and their health? Help Please!

Comment: This is in Spritekit btw

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there are many ways of doing this, but if you are using GameplayKit's Entities and Components, then it would be logical to store this kind of data in a health component.

In general, if your game is getting complex, have a look at GameplayKit's guidelines and likely you will find all the answers.